# Select Box options not visible in Internet Explorer for wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, select, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

I am facing problem with the select box, options are not visible on my wordpress site. I have extracted the country name from an xml file using JavaScript and used as the options of the select box. `Firefox` and `Chrome` shows the options as required but `IE` does not show the options of countries. Could you please help me how can I resolve this problem and show same as Chrome and firefox dpes.

[Here is my site](http://rabbitrabbitmobile.net/) and the code is given below :

```
$(function() { 
    $.get( 'ttalk.xml', {}, function(data) { 
        var optionHtml = '<option value="Please Select" selected="selected">Please Select</option>';
        $(data).find('item').each(function() {
            var _item = $(this);
            html = '<option value=' + _item.find('code').text() + '>';
            var name = _item.find('country').text();
            html += name.split('+').join(' ')+ '</option>';
            optionHtml += html; 
        });  
        $('#destinationList').html(optionHtml);
        $('#destination').html(optionHtml);
    }, 'text' ); 
});
```

Comment: Where is the code that you have used ?

Comment: Here is the code which I have used for parsing the select box options from a xml file.

`code`
$(function() {
$.get(
'ttalk.xml',
{},
function(data) {
var optionHtml = '<option value="Please Select" selected="selected">Please Select</option>'; 
    $(data).find('item').each(function() {
var _item = $(this);
html = '<option value=' + _item.find('code').text() + '>';
var name = _item.find('country').text();
html += name.split('+').join(' ')+ '</option>';
optionHtml += html;
});    $('#destinationList').html(optionHtml);
$('#destination').html(optionHtml);
},
'text'
);
});
`code`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$(function() {
    var xml;
    $.get( 'ttalk.xml', {}, function(data) { 
        if ($.browser.msie)
        {
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.loadXML(data);
            xml = xmlDoc;
        }
        else xml = data;

        var optionHtml = '<option value="Please Select" selected="selected">Please Select</option>';
        $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
            var _item = $(this);
            html = '<option value=' + _item.find('code').text() + '>';
            var name = _item.find('country').text();
            html += name.split('+').join(' ')+ '</option>';
            optionHtml += html; 
        });  
        $('#destinationList').html(optionHtml);
        $('#destination').html(optionHtml);
    }, 'text' ); 
});
```

Comment: Sheikh Heera, Thanks for your reply. I have tested my site using your code but using this code the select box options are not visible on any browser. Here is the xml file url: 
http://rabbitrabbitmobile.net/ttalk.xml

Comment: @SujanKumarBiswas, I've updated the answer, there was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have an issue with the encoding of the xml doc.
Web Dev toolbar is show me this error.

While it still works in FF and Chrome, IE8 may be having extreme issues with it.

```
Timestamp: 13-03-16 6:23:09 PM
Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Source File: http://rabbitrabbitmobile.net/ttalk.xml
Line: 2, Column: 1
Source Code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><CHANNEL>
```

-d